# Android MediaPlayer fails with status 0x64

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, fileinputstream

I am using the following code:

```
          try {
            File f = new File(getVideoUrl(listVideoUrls.get(0)));
            Log.d("MediaPlayer","Fexists?"+f.exists());
            MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
            pl.setDataSource(fi.getFD());
            pl.prepare();
            pl.start();
            Log.d("MediaPlayer","MediaPlayer startet.");
          } catch (Exception e) { alert(e.getMessage()); }
```

But it is failing with the message

> android mediaplayer prepare failed status 0x64

I don't understand why. The file exists (`file.exists()` is true) and is placed at `/Android/obb/de.blub.kaese/video.mp4`.

Comment: try to use `pl.prepareAsync()`, then do an `OnPreparedListener()` for `pl` and within the listener do `pl.start()`

Comment: Try just using `setDataSource(String path)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Comment: @kabuto178: thx but the onPrepared function is never called. Code: pl.prepareAsync();
  pl.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer pl) {
       pl.start();
       }
     }); I tried this before with an videoview too but also there it was no callback to onPrepared ... at Ken: I need to open an not worldreadable file so I have to stream it. Opening the direct path does not work.

Comment: This is the preferred method to loading big media as calling `start()` directly after `prepare()` might not work as media is still being loaded/buffered. Do you get an error in `logcat` after using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by `release()` method

so try following code

```
try {
    File f = new File(getVideoUrl(listVideoUrls.get(0)));
    Log.d("MediaPlayer","Fexists?"+f.exists());
    MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
    pl.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
    pl.setDataSource(fi.getFD());
    pl.prepare();
    pl.start();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer","MediaPlayer startet.");
} catch (Exception e) { alert(e.getMessage()); }
```